# stop executing after mysqli_connect('','','')

Tags: php, mysqli

i have wriiten a a code in php...

```
<?php
 echo "entering db php code";
 $link=mysqli_connect ('localhost','root','MyRootPassword');
 echo "mysqli_connect is called";
 if (!$link)
 {
     echo "cannection is failed";
     exit();    
 }
 echo "connection is ok";
 ?>
```

output is::

> entering db php code

that's it.***the code stop executing after mysqli_connect() call.***
can anyone please tell me that.what is the problem in the code.
this code is absolutely doing nothing with the mysqli_connect() call and it stop executing the rest part once mysqli_connect is called

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should enable error displaying like:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

But if you never get to the second `echo`, that probably means that the `mysqli` extension is not installed and you get an `undefined function` error, stopping your script.

Does `phpinfo();` give you a section with mysqli information?

Comment: thanks a lot...then please tell me how to establish the mysqli extension @jeroen

Comment: @Ritabrata Gautam That depends on your hosting solution, some allow for easy addition of extensions and if you manage the machine yourself, you could probably simply install it.

Comment: Strict Standards: main() [function.main]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. Please use the date.timezone setting, the TZ environment variable or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'UTC' for '5.5/no DST' instead in C:\Program Files\Apache Group\Apache2\htdocs\include\db.inc.php on line 16

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in C:\Program Files\Apache Group\Apache2\htdocs\include\db.inc.php on line 16

Comment: @jeroen..am sorry..if you are filling disturbed....but above is the error..can u explainit for me please..everything going over my hhead

Comment: @Ritabrata Gautam exactly, you (your host...) need to add / install the `mysqli` extension or alternatively switch to `PDO` if that is installed already.

Comment: i checked my php folder..and there is nothing in the ext subfolder..that's extension_dir in php-ini file is pointing to  void as there is nothing in ext subfolder....i think i need to re-install php 5.1.x..what say?..@jeroen

Answer (score 3):

```
$link=mysqli_connect ('localhost','root','MyRootPassword');
```

is missing an argument.

The correct way to call `mysqli_connect` is

```
$link = mysqli_connect('server', 'username', 'password', 'database_name');
```

Alternatively, you can define the following in your `php.ini` file

```
mysqli.default_host
mysqli.default_user
mysqli.default_pw
mysqli.default_db
mysqli.default_port //You should only need to change this rarely
mysqli.default_socket //You should only need to change this rarely
```

And call the mysqli_connect as

```
$link = mysqli_connect();
```

Comment: As far as I can see, that (and the rest...) is an optional argument.

Comment: Actually, all of them are optional, if you have them defined them in the php.ini file.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I meant with `and the rest...`.

Comment: thanks for a quick reply..but it doesn't work..i even tried with other arguments like socket and port_no. .... i think there must be some other problem...even if there was any fault with arguments it should show a error message..but the code stop executing after $link=mysqli_connect() call

Comment: Nice explanation, but I still don't see how that would cause the script to exit.

Comment: Well, you already gave the explanation on what would cause the script to exit in the middle of execution. I didn't want to say almost the same thing, except that I would change the error_reporting to E_ALL.

Comment: still am blind...dont know what wrong i have done.. :(...what should i do to establish a successfull connection..

Comment: @RitabrataGautam please see Jeroen's answer.

Comment: Fair enough, sorry to be a pain :-)

Comment: Well, you did catch the correct error. I started thinking on those lines after what I wrote initially didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved it :D :)
earlier i have installed php installer version.i uninstalled it.and then unzip the php 5.2.x thread safe.now it's working after the necessary configuration ...